# Spring Boot application - not reading application.properties in Tomcat, but works under Spring Tool Suite

Tags: spring-boot

I wrote a Spring Boot web application. The application runs under Spring Tool Suite fine, however, when I deploy in Tomcat, it is not able to read the configuration values. I *think* the difference is how the application being run. Any help or suggestions will be highly appreciated. I know this question has been asked many times - I did try all the solutions suggested, but did not have any luck.

Here is the code/config I have:

**TestApplication.java**

```
package com.example.test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AutowireCapableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
  @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application)
    {
        return application.sources(TestApplication.class);
    }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);

    ServiceConfig bean = ServiceConfig.getServiceConfig();
    AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    factory.autowireBean( bean );
    factory.initializeBean( bean, "ServiceConfig" );
  }
}
```

**TestController.java**

```
package com.example.test;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@RestController
public class TestController
{
  @GetMapping(value = "/")
  public String index()
  {
    return "Hello from " + ServiceConfig.getServiceConfig().getName();
  }
}
```

**ServletInitializer.java**

```
package com.example.test;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(TestApplication.class);
    }

}
```

**ServiceConfig.java**

```
package com.example.test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("ServiceConfig")
public class ServiceConfig
{
  static private ServiceConfig serviceConfig = null;

  @Value("${spring.application.name}")
  private String name;

  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  private ServiceConfig() {}

  public static ServiceConfig getServiceConfig()
  {
    if (serviceConfig == null) {
      serviceConfig = new ServiceConfig();
    }

    return serviceConfig;
  }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>test</name>
  <description>Spring Boot Test Application</description>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>com.example.test.TestApplication</start-class>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <finalName>test</finalName>                   
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.application.name = Test-Service
```

**Deployment Steps:**

```
(1) Build the war file: mvn clean install
(2) Copy the generated test.war under Tomcat /webapps directory.
(3) Start tomcat using /bin/start.sh
```

**Issue:**

When I browse http://localhost:8080/test, I see the configuration parameter is not being populated:

```
Hello from null
```

However, I tried to run under Spring Tool Suite, I see the service running at  http://localhost:8080 and the code works:

```
Hello from Test-Service
```

---

---

### UPDATED WITH RESOLUTION

---

---

As pointed out by Andy Wilkinson, the main class was not being called by the war file, and therefore the the configurations were not loaded.

The reason I added the adhoc initilization of the ServiceConfig bean is that the @Component annotation was not automatically loading the application.properties in the ServiceConfig class. Anyway, I finally used Java's @PostConstruct annotation that works both for independent Java application or war based Tomcat application:

Here is the updated code:

**TestApplication.java**

```
package com.example.test;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AutowireCapableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application)
    {
        return application.sources(TestApplication.class);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {       
        ServiceConfig bean = ServiceConfig.getServiceConfig();
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = appContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        factory.autowireBean( bean );
        factory.initializeBean( bean, "ServiceConfig" );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);     

    }
}
```

Thanks @Andy Wilkinson again for your help!

Best Regards,
MN

Comment: Where, in relation to your pom.xml file, is `application.properties`? It needs to be packaged into `WEB-INF/classes` in the war file so it should be in `src/main/resources`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deployed as a war file, your application’s main method isn’t called. Crucially in this case, this means that the following code doesn’t get called:

```java
ServiceConfig bean = ServiceConfig.getServiceConfig();
AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
factory.autowireBean( bean );
factory.initializeBean( bean, "ServiceConfig" );
```

Without this code being called, the `ServiceConfig` that `TestController` retrieves hasn’t been initialised and, therefore, its `name` field is `null`.

The code to initialise `ServiceConfig` is unconventional for a Spring Boot application. I would remove it entirely and rely on a `ServiceConfig` bean being created and initialised automatically by virtue of its `@Component` annotation. With this code removed, you then need to update your controller to inject the dependency. I’d use constructor injection for that:

```java
@RestController
public class TestController
{
  private final ServiceConfig serviceConfig;

  TestController(ServiceConfig ServiceConfig) {
    this.serviceConfig = serviceConfig;
  }

  @GetMapping(value = "/")
  public String index()
  {
    return "Hello from " + this.serviceConfig.getName();
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! Yes, the main class was not being called by the war file, and therefore the the config was not loaded. The reason I added the adhoc initialization of the ServiceConfig bean is that the Component annotation was not automatically loading the application.properties in the ServiceConfig class. Anyway, I finally used Java's PostConstruct annotation that works both for independent Java application or war based Tomcat application.

Comment: Btw, I am still curious why the Component and Value annotations did not work in the ServiceConfig.java  automatically. Is this something because I am  creating a  ServiceConfig instance using Singleton pattern? In that case, how does this pattern typically used with Spring Boot?

Comment: They had no effect as you are creating the `ServiceConfig` instance rather than letting Spring do it. A Spring bean is a singleton by default. As I suggest above, you should delete your code that create and initialises a `ServiceConfig` instance and inject the Spring-creates instance into your controller instead.

Comment: So if I need to access a config value from multiple classes, I will need to define the same attribute in each class and use the Value annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Move your application.properties file into /webapps directory will solve this issue.

Comment: This will make it remotely accessibly over HTTP. That’s a risky thing to do, particularly as it may contain usernames and passwords.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Thomas,. I tried moving the application.properties into /webapps directory, but still seeing null. Please let me know if you have any other inputs.

Comment: @Andy, any recommendation from your side? Thanks!

Comment: @MNWA I left a comment on the question yesterday. My suspicion is that `application.properties` isn't getting packaged in your `.war` file or it's getting packaged in the wrong location.

Comment: @Andy, sorry, missed that comment. Yes, the application.properties is under /src/main/resources. And I verified the file is getting packaged in the war file under WEB-INF\classes\. Thanks!

Comment: may be you need to set enviroment variable SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION for you application